# httpPost don't fill the listview

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have this class for HttpPost method:

```
public class httpHandler {

public String post(String posturl, String where){

  try {

      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);

      //AÑADIR PARAMETROS
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",where));

       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

              /*Finalmente ejecutamos enviando la info al server*/
      HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();/*y obtenemos una respuesta*/

      String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

      return text;

      }
      catch(Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "error";}

}

}
```

Then, in the asyntask I execute this class and fill a listview with that httpost:

```
class AsyncExecute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {
                // Llamamos al servicio web para recuperar los datos
           httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
                String txt = handler.post("url", "pedro");  
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(txt);
                JSONArray cities = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cities");

                // Recorremos el array con los elementos cities
                for(int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject city = cities.getJSONObject(i);
                  // Creamos el objeto City
                  City c = new City(city.getString("name"),   
                 city.getInt("nametwo"),city.getString("posicion") );
                  c.setData(city.getString("photo"));


                  listaPersonas.add(c.photo);
                  // Almacenamos el objeto en el array que hemos creado anteriormente
                  citiesAvaiable.add(c);

                }
              }
              catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Creamos el objeto CityAdapter y lo asignamos al ListView 

         CityAdapter cityAdapter = new CityAdapter(MainActivity.this, citiesAvaiable);
         lvCities.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

then I execute that asynctask in button click, but the listview doesn't fill.

the json php is:

```
<?php  

$con = mysql_connect('mysql.hostinger.es', 'u453215752_aitor', '*****');  
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  
$dato = $_POST['data'];
$cities['cities'] = array();

if( $con )  
{  
mysql_select_db('u453215752_droid');  

$res = mysql_query('select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where  
name='$dato'');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
array_push($cities['cities'], array('posicion' => $row['posicion'], 'name' =>  
$row['name'], 'nametwo' => $row['nametwo'], 'photo' => base64_encode($row['photo'])));
}
mysql_free_result($res);
mysql_close($con);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($cities);
```

Comment: Where are you adding data to a ListView? What are listaPersonas and citiesAvailable? If those are adapters, then you should modify your AsyncTask to return a City object from doInBackground, and then add the items to your adapter in postExecute. You need to modify UI objects in the UI thread, and postExecute is called on the UI thread.

Comment: I put data into a variable in the php and i use it for the where query  but I don't know how recive the array from json and put into the adapter.  I have edited the Asynctask part in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both a POST and a GET connection to the same url. That makes no sense. The php script can only handle a POST. And your Android code does noting with the received json text `txt` that is sent from the php script after receiving the post.

Remove the httpget completely. Only POST. Use `txt` not `aux`.

You only need:

```
txt = handler.post("http://.......php", "pedro"); 
if ( txt.equals("error" ) )
    return null;
if ( txt.startsWith("<br" ) )
    return null;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(txt);
```

Change

```
$res = mysql_query('select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where  
name='$dato'');
```

to one of these

```
$query = "select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where name='$dato'";    
$query = "select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where name=\'$dato\'";    
$query = "select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where name=$dato";

$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: can you show me it in a code please, I dont understand completly that I have to do.

Comment: I have edited the doInbackground method in the first post, see it please, thanks you

Comment: So remove all lines with BufferedReader, StringBuilder and String line.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see the "between", sorry I am spanish.
I have edit the first post; and throws the error: value <br java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: Well `txt` should only contain json text. Does it contain a `<br` ? That is invalid. You first should investigate what `txt` contains before using it. So `Log.d( "txt",  txt);` it so you can see.

Comment: If i try your url in a browser (so a get request) the response is: `<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in <b>/home/u453215752/public_html/nombreb.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />`. So maybe you got the same as that `<br` is here too.

Comment: <b><parse error><b>: syntaxis error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in  in /home/u453215752/public_html/nombreb.php on line 13

Comment: Please comment on this result. We all expect you to do so.

Comment: yes, I have got the same in the log: <b><parse error><b>: syntaxis error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in in /home/u453215752/public_html/nombreb.php on line 13

Comment: That you alreaady told. You do not have to repeat yourself. Instead you are supposed to comment on this error. So why is there an error? In which line you should tell. And what are you going to do now?

Comment: I have got the php code in the first, I dont know why gets that error. I want use the variable $dato (that is recived with "pedro") in the where query

Comment: To prevent abuse of  your site i advise you to use a fake url in your post. I meanwhile did too ;-).

Comment: The error is on line 13. So look which code line that is. And tell us which code is on that line. And look if you see errors. Do you understand that error? Tell us!

Comment: thank you, really! so in the line 13 there is $res = mysql_query('select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where name='$dato''); I think that error is because php doesn't put the variable $data, but I have declared it in $dato = $_POST['data'];

Comment: No. Line 13 is only `$res = mysql_query('select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where` . The rest is on line 14 as it looks here. Make one line from it. But then you will still have an error im afraid.

Comment: Thanks you!!! Works fine with the editted code on the mysql query!
$query = "select name, nametwo, photo, posicion from cities where name='$dato'";    
$res = mysql_query($query);